# Get ref code from a product combination in Prestashop

Tags: reference, prestashop, combinations

I have a product in my shop, with a reference code. This ref code is visible in product page.
I made a combination for this product, with a new reference code. How can I get and put this ref code on the product page??

Answer (score 0):

By default `product.js` code changes the product reference depending on which combination is selected. If you're not seeing reference or price change, it may be that there is a JavaScript error in your page.

See this code
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/js/product.js#L649